# Execute sql scripts on mysql server using python

Tags: python, mysql-5.7

I have a folder with SQL scripts that have to be executed in a MySQL server.

These scripts could contain any SQL statements.

I would like to automate the execution of those scripts.

I am more comfortable with Python. I have done some initial research finding ODBM for MySQL and python (MySQL-connector but I don't think I can use it for this task)

Any suggestions on how should I tackle this problem?

This is for a MySQL 5.7 and Python2.7 running on Linux. As a starting point, the sql scripts are stored in the same machine as the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sqlalchemy` library is great for executing raw SQL statements agains databases, and it has the benefit of being dynamic and agnostic of the DBMS you're currently using, so the script you develop using it can be applied to other databases if you want to (docs for sqlalchemy: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html).

To open a connection and execute SQL commands on it is straightforward:

```
engine = create_engine('mysql://scott:tiger@localhost/test')
conn = engine.connect()
result = engine.execute('select * from table')
```

As for executing the SQLs that are located in a subdirectory, you can use the `os.walk` function like this:

```
sql_files_path = '/path/to/sql/files'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(sql_files_path):
    for f in files:
         conn.execute(f.read())
```

As for your decision to use `python2.7` I'd really recommend that you change to `python3.x` since you're at the beginning of a project and the support to `python2.7` is scheduled to end in 7 months: https://pythonclock.org/